# Differentiating いなくなる as "not being around" versus "not being around (because of being dead)"?

Tags: word-choice, nuances

At first I learnt いなくなる as the polite version of 死んだ/死んでいる, then I realised it could also be used as a negative version of いる to indicate state of existing/being in a place.
Then how do you potentially avoid having, E.g., "if　〇〇 is not around, then what would you do" vs "if 〇〇 is dead, then what would you do" confused?

Comment: But the polite version of 死ぬ is 亡くなる.

Answer (score 1):

It is nakunatta((亡くなった)) that means died....not inakunatta((いなくなった)). 
That is a polite way to say "he died"....かれは亡くなりました (nakunarimashita).

1....if your husband was not around, then what would you do? 。。。いなかったら

2....if your husband died, then what would you do?。。。なくなったら

Comment: Since this answer doesn't actually directly address what it does mean, いなくなる (=いない + なる) actually means _become not here_, that is it means "to disappear", so "3....if your husband disappeared, then what would you do? 。。。いなくなったら"